# Product of mutable data type with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

The program works fine but I need to edit the program **twice**. First program, I need to clear the value of `n`  but I still need to return the product of the digits. The second program, I need to restore the value of `n` but also I still need to store the value of the digit.

The method `int r1 = n.divideBy10();`  is gonna divide `n` by 10 and store the reminder in `r1`. The method `n.multiplyBy10(r1);` is gonna multiply `n` by 10 and adds `r1` and it is a void method.

````
private static NaturalNumber productOfDigits1(NaturalNumber n) {

        int r1 = n.divideBy10();                     // n=1 , r1= 2

        NaturalNumber zero = new NaturalNumber2(0);

        

        if (n.isZero()) {                        // Takes care of numbers 0-9

            n.multiplyBy10(r1);
        } else if (r1 == 0) {                   // works for these numbers [10,20,30...etc]

            n.divideBy10();
        }

        else {   // This is supposed to take care of the rest possible combination of numbers.
           

             NaturalNumber r11 = new NaturalNumber2(r1);
            productOfDigits1(r11);
            n.multiply(r11);
        }
        // n.clear();
        return n;
    }```
````

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: 1 -How can I clear the value of n while still returning the product?    2-How can I restore the value of n while still returning the product?    Both are different cases that use the same code.